# can't deal with the functions provided in fineUploader Plugin ,

Tags: fine-uploader

below 3 function didn't work

- /*getFile(id);  => here's the second */
- /* getEndpoint(id);  => here's the third */
- /* uploadStoredFiles ();   => here's the first */
  so what's wronge , with the code ?

  ```
   <script>
                  var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                  debug: true,
                  element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
                  request: {
                   endpoint: "endpoint.php"
                  },
              chunking: {
              enabled: true,
             concurrent: {
             enabled: true
               },
  success: {
   endpoint: "endpoint.php?done"
      }
       },
  deleteFile: {
      enabled: true,
      endpoint: "endpoint.php"
      },

       retry: {
      enableAuto: true,
      showButton: true
      },

      autoUpload:false,
  ```

  uploadStoredFiles ();  /* => here's the first */

  ```
                                                  callbacks: {
                                                   onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                                                  alert(qq.format("Error on file number {} - {}.  Reason: {}", id, name, errorReason));
                                              },
                                              onComplete:function(id,name,responseJSON,xhr){ 
                                                  alert(getFile(id)); /* => here's the second */
                                                  alert(getEndpoint(id)); /* => here's the third */
       }

                                          },

                                          </script>
  ```

Comment: I rolled back your recent edits. Please do not change your question to match advice in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about fine uploader in terms of calling methods. As with any object, you must call object specific methods on the actual object. Methods are not magically added to the global scope for you.

Outside of your callback handlers, you must call these methods on an instance of the uploader. In your case (since you have already assigned the constructed instance to a variable named `uploader`): `uploader.uploadStoredFiles()`.

Inside of a callback handler (such as `onComplete`), you can call methods on `this`, for example: `this.getFile(id)`.

Comment: i modified the code , and already the functions with object name.method didn't work , please tell me what's wrong with that

Comment: @youhana I suggest you spend some time learning the basics of JavaScript before you go any further.